# What is non-characteristics harmonics and inter-harmonics in HVDC?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

I have only heard about harmonics in AC power, but in the HVDC system, these terms are used. How do they affect the system?

Comment: Since harmonics are generally a meaningless term in DC, I think some references or links are required. It's possible this refers to the AC interfaces at the end of an HVDC link.